# How to compare the values of two nodes in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm aware this is probably a duplicate, but I'm going to try anyway :)

I have an XML file from which I get criteria values.
The XML file looks like this:

```
<root>
<test>
    <criteria nom="DR">
        <abbr>DR</abbr>
        <value>0.123456</value>
    </criteria>
    <criteria nom="MOTA">
        <abbr>MOTA</abbr>
        <value>0.132465</value>
    </criteria>
    </criteria>
</test>
<test>
    <criteria nom="DR">
        <abbr>DR</abbr>
        <value>0.655425</value>
    </criteria>
    <criteria nom="MOTA">
        <abbr>MOTA</abbr>
        <value>0.766545</value>
    </criteria>
</test>
</root>
```

and I'm trying to compare the fields `<value>`.
For now I'm trying to do it this way:

```
<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
<xsl:for-each select="/root/test[$pos]/criteria/value">
    <xsl:if test="/root/test[$pos-1]/criteria/value/text() &lt; /root/test[$pos]/criteria/value/text()">
        <td class = "GOOD"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="/root/test[$pos-1]/criteria/value/text() &gt; /root/test[$pos]/criteria/value/text()">
        <td class = "BAD"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but this isn't the right way to do it.
How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the current element is `value`, a quite elegant way to refer
to the "previous" value (within the current `test` element) is:

```
select="../preceding-sibling::*[1]/value"
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/93nvfcY

Note that your source XML contains within each `test` element only one `criteria`
element which has a preceding sibling, so for demontration purpose I extended it
by additional `criteria` element in the first `test`.

Visit the above mentioned page and experiment with changing values of `value`
elements in the source XML pane.